# VDrift does not start

Tags: kubuntu, games

I tried to install VDrift on Kubuntu 11.10. I downloaded the source from the project's website, installed the dependencies from packages and Bullet by hand.

When I try to launch VDrift, I now get that:

## STDOUT

```
INFO: Multi-processor system detected.  Run with -multithreaded argument to enable multithreading (EXPERIMENTAL).
INFO: Starting VDrift: development-full, Version: exportiert, O/S: Unix
INFO: Home directory: /home/mu
INFO: Settings file: /home/mu/.vdrift/VDrift.config (does not exist, will be created)
INFO: Data directory: /usr/local/share/games/vdrift/data
      DATA_DIR: /usr/local/share/games/vdrift/data
INFO: Temporary directory: /home/mu/.vdrift/tmp
INFO: Log file: /home/mu/.vdrift/log.txt
INFO: The last VDrift startup was unsuccessful.
      Settings have been set to failsafe defaults.
      Your original VDrift.config file was backed up to VDrift.config.backup
INFO: Disabling antialiasing
INFO: Display change was successful: 800x600x16 16z fullscreen=0
INFO: Video card information:
      Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
      Renderer: GeForce 9500 GT/PCI/SSE2
      Version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 280.13
      Maximum texture size: 8192
      Maximum varying floats: 60
      Using GLEW 1.6.0
INFO: Maximum color attachments: 8
INFO: Maximum draw buffers (1 required): 8
INFO: Disabling shaders
INFO: SIGABRT detected, releasing the mouse
```

## STDERR

```
ERROR: Failed to load /home/mu/.vdrift/VDrift.config
ERROR: Unable to open graphics config file: /usr/local/share/games/vdrift/data/shaders/render.conf.noshaders
ERROR: Error loading non-shader render configuration file: /usr/local/share/games/vdrift/data/shaders/render.conf.noshaders
vdrift: src/graphics_fallback.cpp:646: void GRAPHICS_FALLBACK::DisableShaders(const string&, std::ostream&): Assertion `0' failed.
```

How can I get it to run?

Comment: File bug report

Comment: There already is this bug. I commented it.

Comment: This question is currently untagged. Please consider selecting a tag for it, to improve the organization of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not checkout the data files from the SVN.